# Linq: Select from 2 datatable where column id from first table = column id from second table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

The SQL would be something like

```
select GeneralData.id, GeneralData.name, GeneralData.last_name, Student.id
from GeneralData Inner JOIN Student ON Student.id=GeneralData.id
```

GeneralData is dt1
Student  is dt2
what I want to get is dt3
have some proposals?

Comment: I think you might need to fix your SQL a bit. You've got a cross join and then an inner join to one of the tables that you already cross joined (it may work but makes no sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var query =
            from s in db.Student
            from g in db.GeneralData
            where s.id == g.id
            select new
            {
                g.id,
                g.name,
                g.last_name
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from data in dc.GeneralData
join stud in dc.Students in data.id equals stud.id
select new
{
 data.id, data.Name, data.LastName, stud.id
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var result= (
        from general in db.GeneralData
        join student in db.Student
            on general.id=student.id
        select new
        {
            general.id,
            general.name,
            general.last_name,
            studentId=student.id
        }
    );
```

where db is the linq data context

Answer (score 1):

As a method chain:

```
dt2.Where(s=>s.id == 1)
.Select(s=> new {Stud = s, Data= dt1.Where(g=>g.id == s.id)}).First()
.Select(q=> new {q.Stud.id, q.Data.name, q.data.last_name}).FirstOrDefault();
```